# swift call function multiple times inside update

Tags: swift, function, sprite-kit

I create a game via SpriteKit. in the game every few second a ball spawn to the screen (via function) and the player has to blow them up. now, I want to check the player level via his score so if the score is bigger than 10 the spawnBall function will be executed twice (so 2 ball will spawn on the screen) an so on. I tried to to it via the update fun (that will "read" the player score and depends on the score will call the spawnBall function). Unfortunately when I do it the screen is spawn with million (or so)  balls in few seconds (as I said I want it to call the function every few seconds and increase the call while the score is X). I really don't have any idea how to do it. 
here is my code:

```
override func update(_ currentTime: CFTimeInterval) {

    if (self.score <= 10){
        spawnBalls()
    }

    if (self.score > 10 && self.score <= 20){
        spawnBalls()
        spawnBalls()
    }

    if (self.score > 20){
        spawnBalls()
        spawnBalls()
        spawnBalls()
    }

    if (self.subscore == 3) {
        _ = randomBallColorToBlow()
        self.subscore = 0
    }
}

func spawnBalls() {
    let wait = SKAction.wait(forDuration: 1)
    let action = SKAction.run {
        self.createBall()
    }
    run(SKAction.repeatForever((SKAction.sequence([wait, action]))))
}
```

how can I do it without using the update function??

Comment: you need to not paste irrelevant code in your question, it makes the code unnecessarily longer and harder to follow

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you are calling spawn balls 60 times a second by calling it in your update func.
try just checking if a certain requirement is met to upgrade to a higher spawn rate in your update but keep the calls out of the update func.

```
private var upgradedToLevel2 = false
private var upgradedToLevel3 = false

//called somewhere probably in a start game func
spawnBalls(duration: 1.0)

override func update(_ currentTime: CFTimeInterval) {

    if (self.score > 10 && self.score <= 20) && !upgradedToLevel2 {
        //this prevents the if loop from running more than once
        upgradedToLevel2 = true 
        self.removeAction(forKey: "spawn")
        spawnBalls(duration: 0.5)
    }

    if (self.score > 20) && !upgradedToLevel3 {
        //this prevents the if loop from running more than once
        upgradedToLevel3 = true
        spawnBalls(duration: 0.33)
    }
}

func spawnBalls(duration: Double) {

    let wait = SKAction.wait(forDuration: duration)
    let action = SKAction.run { self.createBall() }
    let repeater = SKAction.repeatForever(SKAction.sequence([wait, action]))

    run(repeater, withKey: "spawn")
}
```

Comment: thank you! its working, can you explain why you set the upgrade vars as private?

Comment: This technically changes the desired behavior of your game.  You are no longer spawning 2 instantly, you are spawning 2 over a smaller duration,  just keep that in mind, otherwise the answer gets you where you need to go.

Comment: you are absolutely correct, I hadn't considered that. I guess it up to the OP to decide if he just wants to speed up the process  or display the balls in clumps

Comment: @omerc it keeps the variables in the scope of the class. If you know that the variable will never be accessed or SHOULD never be accessed outside of the scope of the class then set it to private. Private will prevent any accidental access and manipulation of properties causing undesired effects. Truthfully if you are a sole developer chance of you accidently tapping into another of your own classes variables is VERY slim, but it's not a bad habit to get into by setting them as private in case one day you might start coding with others.

Answer (score 1):

As stated, you are spawning your balls multiple times and need to break it up.  I would recommend keeping track of level using an Int instead of a bool to be able to handle an "infinite" amount of level ups without making an "infinite" amount of boolean variables

```
private var nextLevel = 0 //Level 0 allows us to spawn a ball on startup, so no need to call spawnBalls anywhere else

override func update(_ currentTime: CFTimeInterval) {

    if (self.score > 10 * nextLevel){
        self.removeAction(forKey: "spawn") //this prevents the if loop from running more than once
        nextLevel += 1
        spawnBalls(count:nextLevel,forDuration:1) //You can change the 1 here if you want to spawn balls at a faster speed,  I would recommend a variable that uses nextLevel in a forumula
    }
}

func spawnBalls(count:Int, forDuration duration:TimeInterval) {
    let range = 0..<count
    let wait = SKAction.wait(forDuration: duration)
    let action = SKAction.run {range.forEach{self.createBall()}}
    let repeater = SKAction.repeatForever(SKAction.sequence([wait, action]))
    removeAction(forKey:"spawn")
    run(repeater, withKey: "spawn")
}
```